# Python-pdb skip code (as in "not execute")

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

Is there a way to skip a line or two altogether in pdb?

Say I have a pdb session:

```
> print 10
  import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
  destroy_the_universe() # side effect
  useful_line()
```

And I want to go straight to useful_line() WITHOUT invoking pdb() once again, or destroying the universe.
Is there a way to skip (i.e. not execute code) what is between

print 10 and useful_line()?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Use the `j`/`jump` command:

test.py contains:

```
def destroy_the_universe():
    raise RuntimeError("Armageddon")

def useful_line():
    print("Kittens-r-us")

print(10)
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
destroy_the_universe()
useful_line()
```

Then:

```
C:\Temp>c:\python34\python test.py
10
> c:\temp\test.py(9)<module>()
-> destroy_the_universe()
(Pdb) l
  4     def useful_line():
  5         print("Kittens-r-us")
  6
  7     print(10)
  8     import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
  9  -> destroy_the_universe()
 10     useful_line()
[EOF]
(Pdb) j 10
> c:\temp\test.py(10)<module>()
-> useful_line()
(Pdb) c
Kittens-r-us
```