Is it possible to change the return value of a function with pdb?
Let's say I have the following code :
def returns_false():
  breakpoint()
  return False

assert(returns_false())
print("Hello world")

Is there a sequence of pdb commands that will print "Hello world" without triggering an AssertionError first ?
I can't modify a single character of this source file, i'm only looking for what I can achieve while it's already running.
What I tried :

return True
s to get in return mode, and then either retval=True or locals()['__return__']=True
interact and then return True but that throws an exception

But none of that change the actual return value

Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27741387/python-pdb-skip-code-as-in-not-execute

Yes, but when in the function, there's no line outside of the function to jump to, and when exiting the function the assert seem to evaluate before I can jump. So basically s s s j 6 fails :-(

The idea is to jump over the function, you don't need to go inside it.

The breakpoint() is inside the function though, so that's where it will break

Well, then have you tried to omit the assertion, like this: python -Om pdb <Your_Module_Name>.py

I have read it. I've played quite a lot with sys.settrace(), and my experience is that if reassign a value to args on return events, it will indeed affect a new value to the var, but that value won't be reflected on what's actually returned to the following call.
Of course, it's possible I've misunderstood, which is why I'm asking questions on SO ^^ but I think at this point, you can believe that I've seriously studied this question and did my due diligence to the best of my capabilities (which are what they are :shrugh: )

What I don't understand is that you seem specifically unhappy I accepted an answer to this question, is that a problem for you ?

This is actually possible in a dynamic language such as Python, where the code is interpreted line by line and can be self-modifying.
You'll have a lot of typing to do, but here's what you can type into the debugger:
import ctypes
tup = returns_false.__code__.co_consts
obj = ctypes.py_object(tup)
pos = ctypes.c_ssize_t(1)
o = ctypes.py_object(True)
ref_count = ctypes.c_long.from_address(id(tup))
original_count = ref_count.value
ref_count.value = 1
ctypes.pythonapi.Py_IncRef(o)
ctypes.pythonapi.PyTuple_SetItem(obj, pos, o)
ref_count.value = original_count
c

This modifies the return value itself in memory, and will cause returns_false to return True instead of False. The subsequent assertion after exiting pdb will pass. There is no sleight-of-hand here, and no modifying of the original source files, we're literally changing the return value at runtime.
The last line here "c" is the shortcut for "continue" in pdb, and will exit the debugger.
Explanation
I'm using Python 3.12.4 here. Some implementation detail may be different in other Python versions, but the same basic technique should work.
For the original source code:
def returns_false():
  breakpoint()
  return False

assert(returns_false())
print("Hello world")

Consider the disassembly of your function using stdlib dis module:
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(returns_false)
  1           0 RESUME                   0

  2           2 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (NULL + breakpoint)
             12 CALL                     0
             20 POP_TOP

  3          22 RETURN_CONST             1 (False)

The last line indicates the return value, RETURN_CONST (False). You'll also see three numbers on the last line of the disassembly:

The 3 refers to the line number of the return statement in the source file.
The 22 is the offset of that instruction within the bytecode.
The 1 is the op arg of the RETURN_CONST op.

This last bullet point is interesting. It actually means the function is returning item 1 from the consts table of the function object. dis has helpfully indicated this item is "False" in parentheses, but it's just rendering whatever item 1 in the consts table is:
>>> returns_false.__code__.co_consts
(None, False)

The consts table will be longer if you have more consts in your function body, for example if you added the line x = 1234 inside the function you'd expect to see 1234 in the consts table, and the return value would now be found at index 2 instead (the pos in my example would also have to be changed accordingly).
So the consts table is a tuple, which is an immutable type, but what if we could modify that tuple (everything in Python is mutable, if you know where to look). Would changing the item at index 1 change the return value of the function? Indeed, it would.
Part of the C API is PyTuple_SetItem

int PyTuple_SetItem(PyObject *p, Py_ssize_t pos, PyObject *o)
Insert a reference to object o at position pos of the tuple pointed to by p. Return 0 on success. If pos is out of bounds, return -1 and set an IndexError exception.

And the CPython devs are even so helpful as to provide a Python API in ctypes.pythonapi to use functions such as PyTuple_SetItem directly from within the runtime.
The rest of the answer is a matter of technique, and some know-how about the implementation, taking care not to cause a segfault or screw up reference counting.
Note that the disassembly of the "hacked" function will respect updates to the consts table, and will now render RETURN_CONST with (True):
>>> returns_false.__code__.co_consts
(None, False)
>>> import ctypes
... tup = returns_false.__code__.co_consts
... obj = ctypes.py_object(tup)
... pos = ctypes.c_ssize_t(1)
... o = ctypes.py_object(True)
... ref_count = ctypes.c_long.from_address(id(tup))
... original_count = ref_count.value
... ref_count.value = 1
... ctypes.pythonapi.Py_IncRef(o)
... ctypes.pythonapi.PyTuple_SetItem(obj, pos, o)
... ref_count.value = original_count
... 
>>> returns_false.__code__.co_consts
(None, True)
>>> returns_false()
> /private/tmp/p.py(3)returns_false()
-> return False
(Pdb) c
True
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(returns_false)
  1           0 RESUME                   0

  2           2 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (NULL + breakpoint)
             12 CALL                     0
             20 POP_TOP

  3          22 RETURN_CONST             1 (True)

Finally, I'll mention that RETURN_CONST is not the only return opcode for a function, in fact it is new in Python 3.12. RETURN_VALUE is likely more common. In other Python 3.x (I've checked 3.6-3.11) your code will use RETURN_VALUE op, but the exact same patch typed verbatim in the debugger will work, because it will just be returning a value which was previously loaded from the consts table onto the stack. The disassembly detail will look different on Python 3.6-3.10, 3.11 and 3.12.
You may also be interested in the Q&A it is possible to monkeypatch a local variable introduced in a function body? where I have demonstrated a similar technique for mutating local variables of a function. In that answer I've also changed the return of a function which was using a RETURN_VALUE opcode.

Not the downvoter, but I suppose the downvote came from the verbosity and fragility of a ctypes hack, but I find it a good read. Voted to undelete and +1 for you.

Note that modifying co_consts works only if the function returns a constant at all, and that this approach wouldn't work if the function returns the result of an expression with for example return x == y.

@blhsing I can only answer the question as asked. Similar technique is always possible in ctypes, or even directly in Python - in that case you could monkeypatch on type(x).__eq__ or just replace x value directly within debugger.

This is extremely fragile, and isn't actually a way to change return values. It alters a function's constant tuple, which affects all uses of that constant anywhere in the function's code. If a function uses a constant for more than just the return value, it'll affect more than what the question asks for, and if a function doesn't return a constant (for example, return sum(l)), it won't work at all. Altering the constant tuple happens to be enough for this very specific function, but it doesn't generalize. Also, it affects all future calls, not just the current call.

The OP does mention that he/she's looking for "a solution that is generally applicable", so I think the gotcha is still notable.

@user2357112 If you don't want it to affect other uses of the consts table, you step to the return statement before applying the patch, and then immediately undo the patch afterwards.

It's undeniable it does answer the question as asked - I will indeed search for a more generally applicable solution for non constant returns, but I think this deserves to be accepted.

This is an ad-hoc hack, which does not answer the question of whether it is possible by standard means to exit an executed function at an arbitrary location by returning an arbitrary value.

Returning the const is the most difficult case to monkeypatch. Overriding returns of variable values is easy in comparison - you can just replace the var within the debugger. If the caller code can be modified the problem is trivial (mock.patch for example). In a sense C4stor has framed the question in the most challenging way possible.

@Vitalizzare I agree, but also the question isn't framed that way. I would still be very curious to get the answer to the more general question, so I'll prepare a new question with a better wording.
I think this question has merit by itself, and even though the answer is ad-hoc, there's still things to learn from it (at least I did learn). I have enough rep to spare to put up more bounties chasing the graal :-D

@wim What would you do in case if all the calculation was placed after return, sort of def f(x): return [x for x in range(x)]? Wouldn't it be easier just run the module with pdb until the line of interest, skip it by jumping and continue?

@Vitalizzare Good question! Set another bounty and I will hunt it  ;)

@wim That question was just a counterexample to the statement that substituting a constant is the hardest thing. If you think it deserves a full answer, you could ask it yourself.

@Vitalizzare You're right, it's a case I hadn't considered when making the statement. Even def f(): return [] seems like it would be difficult to monkeypatch.

You can set a breakpoint at the line that calls returns_false when you load the script with pdb so that you can enter a break before the call, at which point you can patch the function to make it return True.
An example session with your sample script as input:
# python -mpdb test.py
> /root/test.py(1)<module>()
-> def returns_false():
(Pdb) b 5
Breakpoint 1 at /root/test.py:5
(Pdb) r
> /root/test.py(5)<module>()
-> assert(returns_false())
(Pdb) !returns_false = lambda: True
(Pdb) r
Hello world
--Return--
> /root/test.py(6)<module>()->None
-> print("Hello world")
(Pdb)

In case returns_false is called by subsequent code you may want to save the original function and restore returns_false with the original after the call to the stub function:
# python -mpdb test.py
> /root/test.py(1)<module>()
-> def returns_false():
(Pdb) b 5
Breakpoint 1 at /root/test.py:5
(Pdb) b 6
Breakpoint 2 at /root/test.py:6
(Pdb) r
> /root/test.py(5)<module>()
-> assert(returns_false())
(Pdb) !orig_returns_false = returns_false; returns_false = lambda: True
(Pdb) r
> /root/test.py(6)<module>()
-> print("Hello world")
(Pdb) !returns_false = orig_returns_false
(Pdb) r
Hello world
--Return--
> /root/test.py(6)<module>()->None
-> print("Hello world")
(Pdb)


To solve your problem, there are at least 6 different methods, each with their own pros and cons. These methods, however, all need some alternations to code and does not use pdb. There is a method using pdb that can minimalize the changes in code. As the pdb method can only be applied in certain situations and is less Pythonic, I will put it last.
The most obviously easy and simple solution is to change the order in which the assert and print are placed, like this:
def returns_false():
  breakpoint()
  return False

print("Hello world")
assert(returns_false())

Another easy way:
def returns_false():
  breakpoint()
  return True

assert(returns_false())
print("Hello world")

However, if you really don't want to change the code, consider running the python file in the command line like this:
python -O test.py

This will disable all asserts in the python file though. If you still don't want that, there are another three options that you can try:

Use a try/except block to catch the AssertionError, like this:

def returns_false():
  breakpoint()
  return False

try:
    assert(returns_false())
except AssertionError:
    print('Assertion Error caught')
print("Hello world")

This will suppress only this assert and not others.

Use a context manager, acting like a try/except:

class AssertSuppressor():
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        return True

with AssertSuppressor():
    assert (returns_false())
print("Hello world")

This will suppress the assert just like the try/except. The problem with this approach is that the print must be situated outside of the with block. A more fancy approach will fix this problem:
class AssertSuppressorFancy():
    def __init__(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        self.func = func
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        # return True here if you still want to suppress the assert, but I don't think it is necessary

with AssertSuppressorFancy(print, 'Hello World'):
    assert(returns_false())

The above context manager takes a callable argument func and arguments (both keyword and positional) to be passed-in to the callable object. It calls func with *args and **kwargs when the with block is completed, no matter there is an exception or not.

Finally, the wrapper implementation is also a good idea:

def wrapper(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
        if ret:
            return ret
        return True
    return inner

@wrapper
def returns_false():
  breakpoint()
  return False
assert(returns_false())
print("Hello world")

Here, I used a nested function to enable the use of the function wrapper as a decorator. Of course, wrapper can be used directly without being applied as a decorator.  This function changes the return value of return_false to True. It will work on any function because it checks whether it returns a true value; if so, it doesn't bother; if not, it returns True.
Letting print('Hello World') run without triggering AssertionError first is best achieved by the methods stated above; that is, either a). the order of assert and print be swapped (code 1);  b). the function return value be changed (code 2);  or c). one of the implementations listed above (try/except, context manager, decorator/wrapper). Of course, setting the -O flag is another viable option, but if you want other asserts in your code to work then that may not be a good choice.
Finally, although I highly recommend one of the above methods, there is actually a way to skip the assert using pdb. Now, if for some reason you really need to only use pdb commands, give this a try:
import pdb

def returns_false():
  # breakpoint() not needed here
  return False

pdb.set_trace()
assert(returns_false())
print("Hello world")

Then, in the console, do this:
> /home/repl/673e9267-383f-4c6f-9338-ccf0a50572a3/main.py(8)<module>()
-> assert(returns_false())
(Pdb) 
l
  3     def returns_false():
  4       # breakpoint() not needed here
  5       return False
  6     
  7     pdb.set_trace()
  8  -> assert(returns_false())
  9     print("Hello world")
[EOF]
(Pdb) 
j 9
> /home/repl/673e9267-383f-4c6f-9338-ccf0a50572a3/main.py(9)<module>()
-> print("Hello world")
(Pdb) 
c
Hello world

Alternatively, you don't want to import pdb and pdb.set_trace(), there is a similar second method to achieve the goal using breakpoint():
def returns_false():
  # breakpoint() not needed here
  return False

breakpoint()
assert(returns_false())
print("Hello world")

and then this in the console:
> /home/repl/f0e3ca08-1383-492f-9245-a1cc19b7f28d/main.py(6)<module>()
-> assert(returns_false())
(Pdb) 
l
  1     def returns_false():
  2       # breakpoint() not needed here
  3       return False
  4     
  5     breakpoint()
  6  -> assert(returns_false())
  7     print("Hello world")
[EOF]
(Pdb) 
j 7
> /home/repl/f0e3ca08-1383-492f-9245-a1cc19b7f28d/main.py(7)<module>()
-> print("Hello world")
(Pdb) 
c
Hello world

Originally, I thought only using pdb wouldn't work because when I tried the above method (both the pdb.set_trace() one and the breakpoint() one), all I get is this:
*** Jump failed: can only jump from a 'line' trace event

It was printed after I entered the j (acronym for jump) command. Later, however, I found out that there was some kind of problem between pdb, the one used here, and ipdb, a descendent of ipdb, which was installed on my computer. To put it simply, those two just don't get along. So, beware: if you have ipdb installed on your computer, the above code will NOT work and results in a cryptic error message. But if you don't have ipdb, then the code above will work just fine. (Note: I ran the above code in an online python interpreter, because I can't get it to work on my computer. I'm still trying to find the issue with ipdb, but I can't yet find the reason.)

You're right that if I was able to breakpoint() outside of the function returning false, I would be able to jump the assert, but sadly in my case i'm not able too, so I have to use what's given to me ! Aka, I can't modify a single line of what's in the sample input I provided.

@C4stor What about the other methods? Or, do you really can't change any line of code? If so, I'm sorry but I think it isn't possible to jump the assert. Probably you should try to omit all asserts using the python -O test.py method listed in my post.

@C4stor You mentioned in your description that you would like a detailed description of the structure of python's execution. I think I can add that as another solution (because my original solution assumes that you can change at least a bit of code. Also, it is already a bit too long). Would you like me to improve my existing answer or add a new one?

@C4stor I've researched all kinds of methods, but none of them seems to work. Can you please explain your problem a bit further? Like, is your example the actual code you are dealing with? And, is it true that you really can't change a single line of code? If so, please explain why. I found out a ton of methods that would work if you could at least change a few lines of code. Also, why can you use breakpoint() and pdb if you can't change any code? Is it there already? Adding these details would really help a LOT.

Hello :-)
I simplified the problem as much as possible to make it reproducible.
In practice what happens is that :


I can run with python -m pdb from scratch


I start debugging


I enter a function f() in a lib we use (hence why I can't touch the code)


The method ends on return(lib_call()) , and I need to simulate what happens on various return values on lib_call() - so I'd like at this point to force f() to return any value I'd like and move forward


The question is meant to correctly emulate those conditions without a huge setup.

I also tried a lot of things, I'm currently checking whether I can change the bytecode in inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_code , but that doesn't seem to work. I also tried using the new sys.monitoring with a callback on Py_RETURN, the callback gets called, but changing retval there does nothing :-( (also I suspect that if retval is a reference instead of just "False" it would maybe work)

@C4stor However, the new solution still adds the line ret_val=True in the function's code. It is true that if ret_val is a reference to a variable then the pdb methods will work, and my new solution is based exactly on that. I've tried a few times and it turns out good. I'm currently researching other methods, like changing the byte codes.

First, you have to run your script:
python -m pdb your_script.py

When the script hits the breakpoint, enter the following:
(Pdb) import code

(Pdb) co = returns_false.__code__

(Pdb) new_co = code.CodeType(co.co_argcount, co.co_posonlyargcount, co.co_kwonlyargcount, co.co_nlocals, co.co_stacksize, co.co_flags, co.co_code[:-2] + b'\x01', co.co_consts, co.co_names, co.co_varnames, co.co_filename, co.co_name, co.co_firstlineno, co.co_lnotab, co.co_freevars, co.co_cellvars)

(Pdb) returns_false.__code__ = new_co

(Pdb) c

The third step specifically creates a new code object with the same properties as the original, except for the last two bytes of the co_code attribute, which represents the bytecode for returning False. You have to replace the last byte with b'\x01', which is the bytecode for returning True.

I like the idea, it doesn't seem to work though :

CodeType is not part of code module, but of types module - which is easy enough to fix
I tried it out, and it didn't work, for two reasons:
a. While the returns_false() method is running, it seems indifferent to the change
b. If I "cheat" and edit the code of the method before it runs, it can't run anymore (I imagine the constructor is not correct, at least not in python 3.9 nor 3.12)


This idea does not work, the existing code in memory will continue to be used - there is nothing watching to see if you've dynamically reassigned the __code__.

If you don't want to change the position of breakpoint(), check this out:
def return_false():
    breakpoint()
    ret_val = False # must define ret_val here
    return ret_val


assert(return_false())
print('Hello World')

Then, in the console:
> /home/repl/aa5ee727-4230-4aa9-b79d-9b3ca437e234/main.py(3)return_false()
-> ret_val = False
(Pdb) 
l
  1     def return_false():
  2         breakpoint()
  3  ->     ret_val = False
  4         return ret_val
  5     
  6     
  7     assert(return_false())
  8     print('Hello World')
[EOF]
(Pdb) 
j 4
> /home/repl/aa5ee727-4230-4aa9-b79d-9b3ca437e234/main.py(4)return_false()
-> return ret_val
(Pdb) 
ret_val=True
(Pdb) 
c
Hello World

However, the method above still changes the code inside the function. If the addition of the line ret_val=True is not acceptable, then this won't work for you. However, there is a high possibility that there will already be a similar line in the code.
Anyway, try the above code out.
Again, the code above is executed in an online Python interpreter, because it doesn't work on my computer.
